# Converting SQL to Linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to convert some SQL Code to c# Linq:

```
SELECT Username, Count(Ticket.TicketId) as 'Tickets Completed'
FROM  Ticket
INNER JOIN TicketStatus ON Ticket.TicketStatusID = TicketStatus.TicketStatusID
INNER JOIN Membership ON Ticket.CompletedBy = Membership.UserId
WHERE Ticket.ClosedDate >= @StartDate
      and Ticket.ClosedDate <= @EndDate
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY 'Tickets Completed' DESC
```

which displays

```
Paul    6
Mike    4
Donna   3
Elliot  2
```

I tried to use Linqer which made this more complicated and didnt return any results:

```
var query = from Ticket in data.Tickets
                join Membership in data.Memberships on new { CompletedBy = Guid.Parse(Ticket.CompletedBy.ToString()) } equals new { CompletedBy = Membership.UserId }
                where
                  Ticket.ClosedDate >= StartDate &&
                  Ticket.ClosedDate <= EndDate
                group new { Membership, Ticket } by new
                {
                    Membership.Username
                } into g
                orderby
                  "Tickets Completed" descending
                select new
                {
                    Username = g.Key.Username,
                    Completed = g.Count(p => p.Ticket.TicketID > 0)
                };
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `data` isn't empty? Are you using an ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CompletedBy` and `UserId` columns are both `uniqueidentifier` in the database, you shouldn't need to do any type conversion.

```
var query = from t in db.ticket
        join ts in db.ticketStatus 
        on t.TicketStatus.ID equals ts.TicketStatusID
        join m in db.Membership 
        on t.CompletedBy equals m.UserId
        where t.ClosedDate >= startDate 
             && t.closedDate <= endDate
        group  t by m.UserName into tGroup
        order by tGroup.Count(t=> t.TicketId) decending
        select new {
          UserName = tGroup.Key,
          TicketCount = tGroup.Count()
        };
```

Comment: Why not just `group t by m.UserName`?  Also it should just be `tGroup.Count()`.

Comment: updated the code.. thanks. had an old rev of the answer still implemented

Comment: this is perfect thank you.  I have been scratching my head for about 4 hours now, you solved it in 4 mins!  Thank you again.